# Microsoft Graph C# SDK - How to access a custodian's OneDrive for Business to view SharedWithMe?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am coding against the Microsoft Graph C# SDK to query a custodian's OneDrive for Business account.

I am building my call as so:

```
public Task<IDriveSharedWithMeCollectionPage> GetSharedWithMeTask(string username)
{
   return this.GraphServiceClient.Drives[username].SharedWithMe().Request().GetAsync();
}
```

When signing in as a `Global Admin` with the following permissions as:

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.ReadWrite.All"
```

I am getting an error:

> Code: accessDenied
>   Message: You can only call view.sharedWithMe on a drive you own.

**Questions:**

I wanted to ask for a sanity check - is it not possible for a `Global Admin` to find the `remoteItems` facet from a custodian's OneDrive for Business account?

Is this feature not implemented or is it how I am creating the call, that is incorrect?

**Update**

After doing some more research I found out that in a `OneDrive for personal` instance - there is a button which allows you to share a folder or loose file. After clicking this button the folder or file will then be viewable in the root folder of the `custodian's` account. This functionality, however, does not exist in `OneDrive for Business`.

Is there a way to mount a shared folder to a custodians root for `OneDrive for Business`?